# Setting object fields in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a class M with two setter methods setA() and setB() which basically sets two fields A and B respectively.

```
Class M {
        private Object A;
        private Object B;

        public void setA (Object A) {
           this.A = A;
        }
        public void setB (Object B) {
           this.B = B;
        }
    }
```

I have two separate builders BuildA and BuildB which takes object of M and build/sets field A and and field B.

```
Class BuildA {
    public void build(M m) {
        // Some code to build A
        m.setA(A);
    }
}


Class BuildB {
        public void build(M m) {
            // Some code to build B
            m.setB(B);
        }
    }
```

If I run these two builders in multi threaded environment, will there be race condition? will it be thread safe?

Comment: Really depends on how you use the objects. That includes getters.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't threadsafe, but not because of a race condition.

A race condition occurs when the system can be in a bad state depending on the order that different threads execute. As you've described it, these fields are independent and there are no invalid states to be avoided.

The problem you have is that the change made by one thread are not guaranteed to be visible to any others. You need a memory barrier to ensure that their actions are seen by everyone. The simplest fix, given the information you provided, is to declare the fields `volatile`.